# Updating indexPath.row after deleting a cell from table view

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a table view with cells that present a different table view when tapped on, according to the indexPath, i.e.:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let nc = UINavigationController()
    let productController = ProductController()
    nc.viewControllers = [productController]

    //Apple
    if (indexPath.row == 0) {
        productController.navigationItem.title = "Apple Products";
    }
    //Google
    if (indexPath.row == 1) {
        productController.navigationItem.title = "Google Products";
    }
    //Twitter
    if (indexPath.row == 2) {
        productController.navigationItem.title = "Twitter Products";
    }
    //Tesla
    if (indexPath.row == 3) {
        productController.navigationItem.title = "Tesla Products";
    }
    //Samsung
    if (indexPath.row == 4) {
        productController.navigationItem.title = "Samsung Products";
    }
    present(nc, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

However when I delete a cell like so....

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)
{
    if editingStyle == .delete
    {
        tableView.beginUpdates()
        CompanyController.companies.remove(at: indexPath.row)
        CompanyController.logos.remove(at: indexPath.row)
        tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .fade)
        tableView.endUpdates()
    }
}
```

....the indexPath isn't updated, so if I delete the Apple cell (at indexPath.row 0), the Google cell takes its place, but still leads to the Apple products page, and so on and so forth for the rest of the companies. I figured the tableView.delete rows line was taking care of that, but it's not. How can I update the indexPath once something is deleted?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't hardcode data and assume specific rows. Put the data into an array and get the values from the array based on the index path. When a row is deleted, update your data model by deleting from the array.

Update your `didSelectRow` method to:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let nc = UINavigationController()
    let productController = ProductController()
    nc.viewControllers = [productController]

    productController.navigationItem.title = CompanyController.companies[indexPath.row]
    present(nc, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Comment: I was under the impression that that's what I was doing - My data is in arrays (companies, logos) and the table is populated using cell.textLabel?.text = CompanyController.companies[indexPath.row]. Then when I delete, I use CompanyController.companies.remove(at: indexPath.row) to delete from the array.

Comment: But you are hardcoding strings and row numbers in your `didSelectRowAt` method. Remove all of those `if` statements and just use `productController.navigationItem.title = CompanyController.companies[indexPath.row]`.

Comment: Ok, now that's awesome! Never thought to do that but its so logical. Really appreciate the help!

Comment: Glad to help. If you ever find yourself writing a bunch of `if` statements like that or hardcoding a bunch of strings, stop and rethink what you are doing. There's almost always a simpler and better way. Enjoy.