# Confused about using UserDefaults to ensure deleted items stay removed in a table view

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift3

EDIT: I've been trying to figure this out for 8 hours now, if someone understands what I'm doing wrong with UserDefaults, please let me know what I need to do. This is driving me insane.

I am populating a tableview with a setPage() function in viewDidLoad (depending on which cell was tapped on the previous tableview)

```
func setPage() {
    let pageTitle = self.navigationItem.title
    let userDefaults = UserDefaults.standard


    let productData = userDefaults.object(forKey: "products") as? [String]
    let productImageData = userDefaults.object(forKey: "productImages") as? [String]

    ProductController.products = productData!
    ProductController.productImages = productImageData!

    switch pageTitle! {
    case "Apple":
        ProductController.products = appleProducts
        ProductController.productImages = appleImages
    case "Google":
        ProductController.products = googleProducts
        ProductController.productImages = googleImages
    case "Twitter":
        ProductController.products = twitterProducts
        ProductController.productImages = twitterImages
    case "Tesla":
        ProductController.products = teslaProducts
        ProductController.productImages = teslaImages
    default:
        ProductController.products = samsungProducts
        ProductController.productImages = samsungImages
    }

    tableView.reloadData()
}
```

and in cellForRowAt indexPath

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellId, for: indexPath) as! ProductCell

    cell.textLabel?.text = ProductController.products[indexPath.row]
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        cell.productLogoView.image = UIImage(named: ProductController.productImages[indexPath.row])!
    }
    return cell
}
```

And here's where I handle deleting cells

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, canEditRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool
{
    return true
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)
{
    if editingStyle == .delete
    {
        tableView.beginUpdates()
        ProductController.products.remove(at: indexPath.row)
        ProductController.productImages.remove(at: indexPath.row)
        tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .fade)

        let userDefaults = UserDefaults.standard
        userDefaults.set(ProductController.products, forKey: "products")
        userDefaults.set(ProductController.productImages, forKey: "productImages")

        tableView.endUpdates()
    }
}
```

If I navigate off the page and then go back, the deleted cell is there again. I realize that this is because I populate the tableView in viewDidLoad and I think using UserDefaults is the way to solve this, but I'm unsure of how to implement it in this situation. I have read the docs and looked around for a solution but I can't find anything that helps me in this particular use case.

How can I get the deleted cell to stay deleted until the app is relaunched?

Initializing the arrays - I have empty arrays of products and productImages, so setPage() checks the title and then populates the empty arrays with the corresponding company's products and product images.

```
    static var products = [String]()
    var appleProducts = ["iPad", "iPod", "iPhone"]
    var googleProducts = ["Search", "Firebase", "Pixel"]
    var twitterProducts = ["Twitter", "Periscope", "Vine"]
    var teslaProducts = ["Tesla Model S", "Tesla Model X", "Tesla Powerwall"]
    var samsungProducts = ["Samsung Galaxy", "Samsung Note", "Samsung Tab"]

    static var productImages = [String]()
    var appleImages = ["iPad", "iPod", "iPhone"]
    var googleImages = ["GoogleLogo", "Firebase", "Pixel"]
    var twitterImages = ["TwitterLogo", "Periscope", "Vine"]
    var teslaImages = ["TeslaS", "TeslaX", "TeslaPowerwall"]
    var samsungImages = ["SamsungGalaxy", "SamsungNote", "SamsungTab"]
```

Comment: do your products and images have any type of unique identifier?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean

Comment: Have you tried any UserDefaults code? Post what's going on with it if there's a problem with it.

Comment: Connor Neville, I edited my post to show the code that I've tried. I'm fairly new, and this is my first time using UserDefaults, so if you know of a way to achieve what I'm looking for (cells staying deleted even after leaving the page), some code would be much appreciated!

Comment: You need to review [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40985917/1226963) to your previous question. The code you posted here violates everything you should have learned from that.

Comment: Hey rmaddy - I think the question here is slightly different because I'm using UserDefaults, my other question didn't involve that.

Comment: @rmaddy, I've updated my question, would you mind taking another look? I'm sick with frustration and would hate to go to bed like this. I've been trying to fix this for 8 hours, and I'm certain that your answer to my previous question is not also the answer to this one, because I was not dealing with user defaults.

Answer (score 1):

`UserDefaults` is just a  bunch of pairs of keys and values. So, you could assign a boolean value ("hidden") for each product:

```
// get the current product - this depends on how your table is set up
let product = products[indexPath.row]
// set the boolean to true for this product
UserDefaults.set(true, forKey: product)
```

Then, wherever you're initializing your products, add:

```
// only include elements that should not be hidden
products = products.filter({ UserDefaults.boolForKey($0) == false })
```

You could also store all of the

Comment: Thanks Connor, was there more to your post? I tried adding your code to my setPage() function and it didn't work. Can you be more specific as to where these will go in my code?